# UIPickerView Methods have UIPickerView Objects as Arguments But Are Unused

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, oop, uipickerview

I'm reading a Swift OOP book and I understand the idea of instance methods having arguments which will be used within the function.  What is unclear is while following online tutorials for UIPickerViews and UITableViews, there are methods that have UIPickerView or UITableView objects as parameters but aren't used in the function.

For example:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows of data
        return gamesList.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        return gamesList[row].name
    }
```

The first parameter pickerView which takes a UIPickerView object isn't used within these functions.  I'm wondering why have them as parameters in the method's signature but these objects are rarely used in tutorials?  Or am I thinking about this incorrectly?

Thank you in advance for any help to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first object from all the `Delegate` and `Datasource` methods that you are talking about is not unused object, it will hold the reference of the current `UIPickerView`, So it will used if you have multiple `UIPickerView` in the same `ViewController`. Same thing goes for all the others control like `UITableView`, `UICollectionView` etc.

For eg if you have 2 `UIPickerView` in the same `Controller` then you can fill the `UIPickerView` by comparing it in the `UIPickerView` methods.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView == firstPickerView {
         return gamesList1.count
    }
    //else return for second pickerView
    return gamesList2.count         
}
```

So you need to compare the `pickerView` reference in all the methods of `UIPickerView` and fill or access the data according to it.